# using if else statement for dynamic table jsp

Tags: java, jsp

EDIT:
I am retrieving an arraylist of data with data like:[category,content,category,content,...],and 
I want to display a table on a JSP page with dynamic data like this:

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
Category of Tweets:
</td>
<td align="center">
All Tweets of User:
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center">
Entertainment
</td>
<td align="center">
Tweet Content
</td>
</tr>
```

But using the source code I have below:

```
<table id="table" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
Category of Tweets:
</td>
<td align="center">
All Tweets of User: <%out.println(userName); %>
</td>
</tr>
<%
for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
%>
<tr>
<td>
<%
if(i%2==0){
String category = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(category);
%>
</td>
<%}else{ %>
<td>
<%
String content = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(content);
}
%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>
```

The browser seems to duplicate extra table tags just before the else statement:

```
<td>

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>

</td>
```

I am lost on how to resolve this.Could anybody tell me how should I amend the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you said " I am retrieving an arraylist of data with data like:[category,content,category,content,...]" and that list contains pair elements you can iterate the list like presented below:

```
<table id="table" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
Category of Tweets:
</td>
<td align="center">
All Tweets of User: <%out.println(userName); %>
</td>
</tr>
<%
for(int i=0;i<stringList.size()/2;i++){
%>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<%
String category = stringList.get(i*2).toString(); 
out.print(category);
%>
</td>
<td align="center">
<%
String content = stringList.get(i*2+1).toString(); 
out.print(content);
%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>
```

Note that category will iterate on elements situated in pair positions and 0 (0,2,4, ...) and content will iterate on elements situated in odd positions (1,3,5, ...)

Comment: @user1828401 if you need a row per category and a row per content, simple replace in my code </td> <td align="center"> to </td></tr><tr><td align="center">. In the code exposed exist only a row with two columns (category, content) because I tried to reflect the table that you ask for.

Comment: Perfect! you can clean the code styling the td tags in some CSS file or better if you can use some custom class. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You were ending `<td>` after you if condition and then starting a new `<td>` before the else.

Just try this one and see if it satisfies your expected output.

```
<td>
<%
if(i%2==0){
String category = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(category);
%>
</td>
<td>
<%
String content = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(content);
}
%>
</td>
```

Comment: What this does is to display everything in 1 row.What I want is to display 1 row with categories only,and the other row with contents only.

Comment: if you want both than why are you using `else` just check my edited answer.

Comment: Check out my edited post,apologies for not describing the scenario more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

check this code this might help you  keep those tr and td tags in conditional statements

```
<table id="table" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
    <td align="center">
    Category of Tweets:
    </td>
    <td align="center">
    All Tweets of User: <%out.println(userName); %>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <%
    for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
    %>

    <%
    if(i%2==0){%><tr>
    <td><%
    String category = stringList.get(i).toString();
    out.print(category);
    %>
    </td></tr>
    <%}else{ %>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <%
    String content = stringList.get(i).toString();
    out.print(content);%>
     </td>
    </tr><%
    }

    }
    %>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<td>
<%
if(i%2==0){
String category = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(category);
}
%>
</td>
<td>
<%
else{
String content = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(content);
}
%>
</td>
```